# Quebra de linha em tabela HTML

Tags: html, breakpoints

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para quebrar a linha nesta tabela na versão mobile do site (@media screen and (max-width: 550px)):

```
<div>
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Qnd. (ex: 01 un)</th>
<th>Comp. (ex: 1,2m)</th>
<th>Larg. (ex: 2,0m)</th>
<th>Alt. (ex: 1,5m)</th>
<th>Peso (ex: 3,0 kg)</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></input></td>
<td><button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML='';calc();">X</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: A princípio a tag `input` não tem tag de fechamento `</input>`.

Comment: Yuri não ficou muito claro, vc quer quebrar a linha dentro do input, quer quebrar as linha da THead, p que vc que dividir em outras linhas?

Answer (score 1):

Quebrar linhas em uma tabela de forma responsiva é complicado porque a própria estrutura da tabela não permite isso.

Você poderia adicionar um `display: block` às células fazendo com que cada uma ocupe uma linha diferente, mas não creio que o resultado fique muito bom, veja:

***É preciso visualizar em tela cheia e redimensionar a janela para menos de 550px.***

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
  td, th{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Qnd. (ex: 01 un)</th>
<th>Comp. (ex: 1,2m)</th>
<th>Larg. (ex: 2,0m)</th>
<th>Alt. (ex: 1,5m)</th>
<th>Peso (ex: 3,0 kg)</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML='';calc();">X</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML='';calc();">X</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Como a sua tabela não possui muitas colunas (apenas 6), **minha sugestão** é torná-la responsiva, se auto-ajustando à resolução da tela. Basta adicionar no CSS `input: width: 100%;`:

```css
input{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>Qnd. (ex: 01 un)</th>
<th>Comp. (ex: 1,2m)</th>
<th>Larg. (ex: 2,0m)</th>
<th>Alt. (ex: 1,5m)</th>
<th>Peso (ex: 3,0 kg)</th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML='';calc();">X</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="calc()"></td>
<td><button onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML='';calc();">X</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

> Uma correção no seu código, é que a tag `<input>` não possui tag de
>   fechamento `</input>`.